# Vector to Raster cannot get output resolution to approximate input points spacing

Tags: qgis-3, rasterization

This issue is about the usage of the Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vestor to Raster) tool, including Georeferenced Units vs Pixels and the error when choosing Georeferenced Units.

I am attempting to convert a point shapefile comprised of 6077 regularly spaced points placed 1 meter apart.  I was hoping for a raster cell for each point that would be 1 meter in size to match the spacing of my points.

Instead the best I can do is set the width to 50.00 (pixels) and the height to 20.00 to get the raster shown in the pics.  When I set it to 300 Width by 200 Height (pixels) I get these spaced out raster cells as shown.

I have tried numerous combinations but no success.

When I try to use Georeferenced Units instead of Pixels, I get the error "ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal, sizes must be larger than zero." as shown in the pic.  I am using EPSG:4326 in each layer.

Can I fix the Georeferenced Units error so perhaps that might yield better results?

Is there a way to rasterize as I am wanting, creating a single cell for each regularly spaced point?

[image: regularly spaced points shapefile]

[image: sample attributes for the points shapefile]

[image: as fine as I can get (50 x 20 px) before other issues]

[image: 300 x 200 px yields lots of no-data holes]

[image: trying to use Georeferenced Units gets this error]

Comment: Your points seem to be in a geographic coordinate system (CRS), not a projected CRS.  Suggest you use EPSG:32617 instead of EPSG:4326. Or specify a pixel size of 0.00001171 which is roughly equivalent to 1 meter @ 40 latitude

Comment: Please add error messages as formatted text, rather than images. It is much easier to debug and will show up in searches for other users.